# What would happen if the reaction of reduction of carboxylic acids by LiAlH4 is carried out in alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds

Which is the intermediate compound in the reduction of carboxylic acids by $\ce{LiAlH4}$ and what would happen if the reduction of carboxylic acids is carried out in alcohol?

From my knowledge I know that a geminal diol is formed and then elimination takes place to form $\ce{R-CH=O}$. If this is reacted with alcohol instead of $\ce{LiAlH4}$ again what are the expected products?

Comment: If you carry it out in alcohol, the LiAlH4 will decompose, perhaps more violently than you might like.

Comment: @ orthocresol would you please give some kind of the mechanism for the decomposition of LAH in alcohol bcoz the answer below is not that satisfying

Comment: What? There's no mechanism for it. It's just an acid-base reaction.

Comment: @mhchem Your comment `%edit` uncommented the `}` and broke the construct. You can always edit out salutations, buzzwords, and [unnecessary "statements of weakness"](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/4945) instead, see the edit history for what I mean.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Oops, the `%edit` should have gone behind the `}`.

Answer (score -6):

Alcohols are not an ideal solvent for LiAlH4, but the main issue is that there is no carboxylic center to where the hydride transfer from LiAlH4 can take place.

[image]

So in this case, the side-reaction between alcohol and LiAlH4 can be regarded to be minimal and the major product will be the alcohol produced from the carboxylic acid.

P.S. : A diagrammatic representation of the reactions for LiAlH4

[image]

Comment: The side reaction between alcohol and LAH is certainly not minimal. It can be violent and cause your reaction mixture to catch fire.